# Entity Framework Many To Many allow duplicates

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many, entity

Is it possible to insert duplicate rows in Many to Many relationship? This is my class:

```
public class EventPaintballBundle
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public int EventID { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int PaintballBundleID { get; set; }

        public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
        public virtual PaintballBundle PaintballBundle { get; set; }

        [Range(1, Int32.MaxValue)]
        public int PersonCount { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to insert second row of those values. The differences are on Date `Date` and `PersonCount` value

```
EventPaintballBundle xx = new EventPaintballBundle() { PaintballBundleID = 1, EventID = 155, Data = DateTime.Now, PersonCount = 5 };
                    dc.EventPaintballBundles.Add(xx);
                    dc.SaveChanges();
```

I'm getting error while I want to insert a duplicate of two keys.

> {"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.EventPaintballBundles'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.EventPaintballBundles'. The
>   duplicate key value is (155, 1).\r\nThe statement has been
>   terminated."}

How to solve this problem?

Comment: could you show how you are creating an `EventPaintballBundle` object and inserting it into your DB?

Comment: Sure, take a look on my edited post

Comment: But you can't insert two rows with the same `EventID` and `PaintballBundleID`,  those are the PKs of your entitty

Comment: You can't insert duplicate primary keys just like people don't have duplicate SSNs. Just leave them alone and the sql server will allocate those keys automatically.

Comment: But I need duplicate with another `Date` and `PersonCount` , then how can I solve this?

Comment: why SHOULD it be a duplicate ?? A database philosophie is : primary keys are always unique, if you need to duplicate something, it CAN'T be the primary key

Comment: If you need to add an entity with the same `eventID` and same `bundleID` then those shall not be your primary key at all

Answer (score 0):

Create a primary key that isn't the combination of :

```
    public int EventID { get; set; }
    public int PaintballBundleID { get; set; }
```

The new primary should be unique and not related to anything that actually exist, this key will exist only to make your model work database wise.

It's a classic mistake : to think your primary key should represent something that exist... NO

I learned it the hard way : even if i think that some combination of existing data will stay forever unique. I don't use it. I ALWAYS create my primary key from my own design, not representing anything real.